# Batch For /F Syntax with %time%

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do I accomplish this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=: " %%a in ('%time%') do set XTime=%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d
```

I'm trying to get the contents of %time% e.g., 16:25:15.65 into 16.25.15.65.

Running the command above gives me:

> The filename, directory name, or
>   volume label syntax is incorrect.

(If it matters I'm on Windows XP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, turns out I just needed double quotes:

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=: " %%a in ("%time%") do set XTime=%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d
```

Comment: Single quotes would tell `for` to interpret it as a command to execute. Since something like `23:36:25,24` can't be executed ...